# jQuery animate toggle show an element only

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm trying to use jQuery to animate and show a hidden element, however at the moment I can only make it so it will toggle the element and not just show it only.

```
$("#testTab").animate({"height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"}, "slow" );
```

Basically I want to achieve:

```
$("#testTab").toggle("slow");
$("#testTab").toggle(true);
```

but that would make a double toggle and both parameters can't go into one toggle?

Comment: Why wouldn't `$.show()` work? Have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just make it so that you click it once, and it animates the showing of it, just use.

```
$("#testTab").show("slow");
```

If you're trying to make so that it toggles (click once it shows, click again and it hides, animation in both directions). Just use the toggle parameter, that's what it does:

```
$("#testTab").toggle("slow");
```

Comment: Ah the problem was the load() before, basically I need it to animate while loading and not one after the other.